# JSON Column formatting round to integer

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have created this script to calculate the number of days from today, but it returns like 20 decimals. How to round to a whole number?

I was trying to do this using `floor()` but I don't understand what the syntax should be like.

Current JSON code I am using:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator": "/",
        "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "-",
                "operands": [
                    "=Number('@now')",
                    "=Number('[$Date]')"
                ]
            },
            86400000
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `floor()` then try below:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=floor((Number('@now')-Number('[$Date]'))/86400000)"
}
```

**Note**:

> **floor**: returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number. - *Only available in SharePoint Online*
>
> - `"txtContent":"=floor(45.5)"` results in 45

**Source**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators)

**Update from Comments**:

Using `operator` and `operands` you can do it like this:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator": "floor",
        "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "/",
                "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "-",
                        "operands": [
                            "=Number('@now')",
                            "=Number('[$Date]')"
                        ]
                    },
                    86400000
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I actually found the source link you added, but didn't yet figure out we can do the calculation without using "operator" and "operand". Thanks for this great example.

ps- to round mathmatically correct, I should add half a day to the calucation

{ 
"elmType": "div", 
 "txtContent": "=floor(((Number('@now')-Number('[$AdditionDate]')+(0.5 * 86400000))/86400000)"
}

Comment: Great. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: I provided the source link just as the reference of **floor()** function.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have provided the solution by using "operator" and "operands".