# Reducing decimal places on percentage

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, json, column-formatting

I would like to reduce the number of decimal places in a calculated column with some JSON formatting.

[image]

I would like to reduce this to 101%. The JSON code I have written is shown below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= '.92', '#ccffcc', '#ffcccc')",
    "display": "table",
    "width": "100%"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=@currentField*100 + '%'",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "display": "table-cell",
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "font-weight": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `floor()` or `ceiling()` in JSON formatting to round the number value.

If you want to use `floor()` then try below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= '.92', '#ccffcc', '#ffcccc')",
    "display": "table",
    "width": "100%"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=floor(@currentField * 100) + '%'",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "display": "table-cell",
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "font-weight": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Similarly, you can use `ceiling()` in JSON formatting.

**Note**:

> **floor**: returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number. - *Only available in SharePoint Online*
>
> - `"txtContent":"=floor(45.5)"` results in 45
>
> **ceiling**: rounds the given number up to the next largest whole number or integer. - *Only available in SharePoint Online*
>
> - `"txtContent":"=floor(45.5)"` results in 46

**Similar thread**: [JSON Column formatting round to integer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277241/json-column-formatting-round-to-integer/277242#277242)

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting syntax reference - operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators)

Comment: Hi @Carson, did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Should `floor()` work in calculated columns? E.g:  `=FLOOR(CompletedStages/TotalStages * 100)`?  It is giving me this error on save:  `The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported`.  Is there any resource that provides a list of all supported Excel functions in calculated columns?

Comment: Can you please [Ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with more details about your requirements? Provide link to your new question here in the comments. I will have a look and will try to answer if I know the answer. If not, it will be open for other community members to answer your question.